# react-native-cli - Fails to run the android project

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-cli

I'm trying to run a React Native project in my Ubuntu 16.04 PC using the `react-native run-android` command. However it gives me the following error.

[image]

The strange thing is that when I create and run an Android project using the Android Studio for the API level 23, it compiles and runs perfectly fine.

Can someone help me with this issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the Gradle version solved my issue.
I went through the following steps.

1. Opened the android folder inside the React Native project using
   Android Studio.
2. Accepted the prompt that shows to update the version
   of Gradle.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you have build-tool version 23.0.1 installed? 
you can check it in your SDK manager
[image]

Comment: does `/home/shan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt` file exist in your computer?

Comment: i hope you dont have multiple Android SDK folder in your computer?

Comment: /home/shan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt Yes this file is there.

Comment: what do you mean by the multiple Android SDK folder?

Comment: the strange thing is that it runs when I run it in Android Studio

Comment: then that could be your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is pointing to the other Android SDK folder... while your android studio is pointing to the one with correct version (23.0.1) build tool installed.....which means, you have multiple Android SDK setup in your computer

Comment: the issue seems to be with the default version of Gradle that gets cretted when using the react-native CLI.